# SQL Server........ backup only a few databases

Tags: sql-server

I am using the stored procedure shown here for taking backups of databases from SQL Server.

It takes all backups for around 20 databases, now I want little change in the stored procedure.

It want below databases backups to pick through loop, how to modify existing stored procedure. Thanks

```
Emp_DB
Salary_DB
Company_DB
Attendance_DB
```

Code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Backupdbs
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE c1 CURSOR FOR
         SELECT name FROM sys.databases WHERE database_id > 4

    DECLARE @dbname varchar(100)
    DECLARE @fname varchar(100)

    OPEN C1

    FETCH NEXT FROM c1 INTO @dbname

    WHILE (@@fetch_status = 0)
        -- here, you're missing a 
        -- BEGIN
        SET @fname = 'D:\Backup\'+@dbname+'.bak'

        BACKUP DATABASE @dbname TO disk=@fname

        FETCH NEXT FROM cl INTO @dbname
    END

    CLOSE c1
    DEALLOCATE c1
END IF
```

Thanks
mg

Comment: Why not just filter by name in your cursor definition?

Answer (score 0):

You could just add the databases in question to your `where` clause in your cursor query against `sys.databases`.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Backupdbs
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE c1 CURSOR FOR
         SELECT name FROM sys.databases WHERE database_id > 4
            and name IN ('Emp_DB','Salary_DB','Company_DB','Attendance_DB')

    DECLARE @dbname varchar(100)
    DECLARE @fname varchar(100)

    OPEN C1

    FETCH NEXT FROM c1 INTO @dbname

    WHILE (@@fetch_status = 0)
        -- here, you're missing a 
        -- BEGIN
        SET @fname = 'D:\Backup\'+@dbname+'.bak'

        BACKUP DATABASE @dbname TO disk=@fname

        FETCH NEXT FROM cl INTO @dbname
    END

    CLOSE c1
    DEALLOCATE c1
END IF
```

Answer (score 0):

A better scalable solution would be to have your own list of database names you want to back up, possibly with a `groupId`.

You can then pass a `@groupId` parameter and run a batch of database backups for the group or set of databases you choose - eg you can group large databases together, small together, frequently modified etc

So for example you could have the following table

```
create table BackupSets (
id int identity(1,1) primary key,
GroupId int,
[Name] sysname
)
```

and use it instead of `sys.databases`

```
select [Name] from BackupSets where groupId=@GroupId
```

You could also have a process as part of your backup to check for any names in `sys.databases` that don't exist in your list and insert them.